# How can I create a copy of an existent contract in Javascript ?

Tags: web3js-v1.x

I'm trying to create a copy of an contract existent contract using web3.js 1.0. I'm trying to use the functions clone and deploy but without success.

```
        contract2 = contract1.clone();

        contract2.deploy().send({from : web3.eth.defaultAccount})
        .on('error', function(error){ 
             alert(error);
         })
         .then(function(result){
            alert(result); 
            } 
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an argument to deploy, this object contains the bytecode and the arguments to pass to the constructor (if any). [See here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#deploy)

The issue is that the contract object does not store the bytecode, you need to provide it to deploy.

hope this helps